Unwanted Splashscreen shows after clicking submit button in apk builds
When I test my app on Expo Go, I get absolutely no errors and my app runs fine. On creating a build, when I try to login and click the sign in button, the app suddenly goes into SplashScreen. The same happens on the signup page too. I've been able to deduce that an asynchronous request triggers this issue. That said, I still don't know how to go about it.This is especially hard to debug as it only shows up on APK builds. I'm using expo and expo router.
app/index.tsx (Login Page)
import loginApi from "@/api/login";
import { useAuthContext } from "@/auth/context";
import { ThemedText } from "@/components/ThemedText";
import AppForm from "@/components/forms/AppForm";
import AppFormField from "@/components/forms/AppFormField";
import SubmitButton from "@/components/forms/SubmitButton";
import { Colors } from "@/constants/Colors";
import useApi from "@/hooks/useApi";
import Constants from "expo-constants";
import { Link } from "expo-router";
import { X } from "lucide-react-native";
import { useState } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';

export interface UserCredentials {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export default function index() {
  const { login,showNotification } = useAuthContext();
  const [loginFailed, setLoginFailed] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().required().email().label("Email"),
    password: Yup.string().required().min(4).label("Password"),
  });
  const {
    loading,
    request: loginRequest,
  } = useApi(loginApi.getLogin);

  const handleSubmit = async({ email, password }: UserCredentials) => {
    const data = { email, password };
    setLoginFailed(false);
    try {
      const response = await loginRequest(data);
      SplashScreen.hideAsync()
      if (response && response.status === 200) {
        login(response.data);
      } else {
        SplashScreen.hideAsync()
        console.log(response.data.non_field_errors);
        showNotification(`Login failed. ${response.data.non_field_errors[0]}`, <X size={16} color="red" fill={"red"} />);
        setLoginFailed(true);
      }
    } catch (error: any) {
      if (error.response && error.response.data) {
        const nonFieldErrors = error.response.data.non_field_errors;
        if (nonFieldErrors && nonFieldErrors.length > 0) {
          showNotification(nonFieldErrors[0], <X size={16} color="red" fill={"red"} />);
        } else {
          showNotification(`Login failed. Please try again. ${error.response.data}`, <X size={16} color="red" fill={"red"} />);
        }
      } else {
        showNotification(`Login failed. Please try again. ${error.message}`, <X size={16} color="red" fill={"red"} />);
      }
      setLoginFailed(true);
    }
  };


  return (
    <View style={styles.Screen}>
      <View style={styles.Top}>
        <Image
          source={require("../assets/images/HopterlinkLogo.png")}
          style={{ width: 150, height: 150, marginTop: 50 }}
          resizeMethod="resize"
          resizeMode="contain"
        />
      </View>
      <View style={{ paddingTop: 30 }}>
        <ThemedText
          darkColor="#000000"
          type="title"
          style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: "800" }}
        >
          Sign In
        </ThemedText>
        <View>
          <AppForm
            initialValues={{ email: "", password: "" }}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
          >
            <AppFormField
              name="email"
              icon="mail"
              style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
              placeholder="Email"
              keyboardType="email-address"
            />
            <AppFormField
              name="password"
              icon="lock"
              style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
              placeholder="Password"
              secureTextEntry={true}
            />
            <Text
              style={{
                color: Colors.primary,
                textAlign: "right",
                marginTop: 10,
                fontWeight: "bold",
                fontSize: 12,
              }}
            >
              Forgot Password?
            </Text>
            {loading ? (
              <View>
                <ActivityIndicator color={Colors.primary} size={"small"} style={{ marginVertical: 20 }} />
              </View>
            ) : (
              <SubmitButton title="Sign In" />
            )}
          </AppForm>
          {loginFailed && (
            <Text style={{ color: 'red', textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 10 }}>
              Login failed. Please try again.
            </Text>
          )}
        </View>
      </View>
      <View style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: "rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.6)",
            textAlign: "center",
            marginTop: 10,
            fontWeight: "bold",
            fontSize: 14,
          }}
        >
          Don’t have an account?{" "}
          <Link style={{ color: Colors.primary }} href="/sign-up">
            Sign Up
          </Link>
        </Text>
        <View>
          <Text
            style={{
              marginTop: 20,
              textAlign: "center",
              fontWeight: "bold",
              fontSize: 14,
            }}
          >
            Social Login
          </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  Screen: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: Colors.light.background,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
  Top: {
    flex: 0.5,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  button: {
    width: "100%",
    padding: 15,
    marginTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: Colors.primary,
    borderRadius: 10,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginVertical: 10,
  },
});

app/_layout.tsx
import { AuthProvider, useAuthContext } from "@/auth/context";
import OfflineNotice from "@/components/OfflineNotice";
import { Colors } from "@/constants/Colors";
import { BottomSheetProvider } from "@/contexts/BottomSheetContext";
import { useFonts } from "expo-font";
import {Stack, useRouter, useSegments } from "expo-router";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { ActivityIndicator, View } from "react-native";
import { GestureHandlerRootView } from "react-native-gesture-handler";
import  * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen';
SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync();

const InitialLayout = () => {
  const [loaded, error] = useFonts({
    SpaceMono: require("../assets/fonts/SpaceMono-Regular.ttf"),
    Proxima: require("../assets/fonts/Proxima-Nova-Font.otf"),
    SFProBold: require("../assets/fonts/SFPRODISPLAYBOLD.otf"),
    SFProMedium: require("../assets/fonts/SFPRODISPLAYMEDIUM.otf"),
    SFProRegular: require("../assets/fonts/SFPRODISPLAYREGULAR.otf"),
  });

  const { user } = useAuthContext();
  const segments = useSegments();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (error) throw error;
  }, [error]);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const inAuthGroup = segments[0] === "(app)";
    if (user && !inAuthGroup) {
      router.replace("/(app)/(tabs)/(home)/home");
    } else if (!user) {
      router.replace("/");
    }
    }, 500);
  }, [user]);

  // Conditional rendering based on font loading and user state
  if (!loaded) {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color={Colors.primary} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  return (
    <Stack>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="index"
        options={{
          presentation:"transparentModal",
          headerShown: false,
        }}
      />
      {/* <Stack.Screen name="login" options={{ headerShown: false }} /> */}
      <Stack.Screen name="sign-up" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="verification" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="(app)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );
};

const RootLayoutNav = () => {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <GestureHandlerRootView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <OfflineNotice />
        <BottomSheetProvider>
          <InitialLayout />
        </BottomSheetProvider>
      </GestureHandlerRootView>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
};


export default RootLayoutNav;

AppForm
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import {
    Formik
  } from 'formik';

  interface AppFormProps {
    initialValues: any;
    onSubmit: (values: any) => void;
    validationSchema: any;
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }

  const AppForm = ({ initialValues, onSubmit, validationSchema, children }:AppFormProps) => {
    return (
        <Formik
            initialValues={initialValues}
            onSubmit={onSubmit}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
        >
            {() => <>{children}</>}
        </Formik>
    );
}
export default AppForm;

    System:
      OS: Windows 11 10.0.22631
    Binaries:
      Node: 19.7.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
      npm: 9.5.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: AI-241.18034.62.2411.12169540       
    npmPackages:
      expo: ~51.0.31 => 51.0.31
      expo-router: ~3.5.23 => 3.5.23
      react: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-dom: 18.2.0 => 18.2.0
      react-native: 0.74.5 => 0.74.5
      react-native-web: ~0.19.10 => 0.19.12
    Expo Workflow: managed

I have commented out sections of the code and have figured out the error occurs on the await function. I have tried manually removing the SplashScreen using splashscreen.hideasync() and still face the issue. I tried making the request using apisauce manually without passing the data into a function, just plain post request in the function and the error still persisted. I tried putting in the wrong credentials and the button just shows the activity indicator then the splash screen pops up again and infinitely stays there just as when I put the right credentials.
